# DJANGO: Change field size of ModelMultipleChoiceField?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, modelform, multiple-choice

I was wondering how one changes the size of a ModelMultipleChoiceField? I've only seen examples of changing a CharField into a Textarea... Is this possible?

Models.PY

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    Person = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False, queryset=Person.objects.all(), attrs={'cols': 50, 'rows': 10})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the width and height of the widget by applying CSS to the `<select>` element that Django creates.

Answer (score 11):

Override the form's `__init__` method and add:

```
self.fields['Person'].widget.attrs['size']='10'
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
from django.forms import widgets
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    Person = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False, queryset=Person.objects.all(), widget=widgets.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size': 20}))
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer. If the form is defined throught he model, use `attrs={'form-control','size': 20}`

Comment: Used forms.SelectMultiple(...) instead of widgets.SelectMultiple and it works